# No product object sharing rule

Tags: trigger, sharing

I need to create a sharing rule for the record type of products in my products object. How can i achieve this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Currently Salesforce doesn't allow you to create sharing rules for products. There isn't really any work around either. [There is an idea on IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp8VAAS), I recommend you vote this up.

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer to  link below for the security based on record type:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hchrAAA